# The program 'app.js' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create my first hello.js app in Visual Studio 22. In started from a blank nodejs console app, and when I run the app I get the following message:

The program 'app.js' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

I'm not understanding if that is an issue or not, since the app prints Hello World as I expect.

Looking around in the web i've found only references about docker containers. Thanks in advance

Comment: A normal _Hello World_ node.js program will exit with code 0.  Perhaps you can give the detailed steps required to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Are you debugging the app?  Because the JavaScript debug adapter for Visual Studio will exit with code -1.  e.g. : `The program 'JavaScript debug adapter: app.js [42964]' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).` `The program '' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).`  is normal.